# Bulk relink child categories to parent categories on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, categories

We recently imported a large product store from Big commerce to woocommerce but have run into an issue regarding the categories.

The products are links to the child category only, meaning if you visit the parent category no products are being shown.

[Product linked to child category but not  parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIwiB.png)

Is there a way to have all child categories relink to the parent category on a large scale? the store has 6000+ products and hundreds of categories so even with bulk editing tools it would take a long time to accomplish this task.

Thank you in advance and apologies if this has already been asked, hard to find the correct wording for this situation.

** I came across this code**

```
add_action('save_post', 'assign_parent_terms', 10, 2);

function assign_parent_terms($post_id, $post){

    if($post->post_type != 'product')
        return $post_id;

    // get all assigned terms   
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach($terms as $term){
        while($term->parent != 0 && !has_term( $term->parent, 'product_cat', $post )){
            // move upward until we get to 0 level terms
            wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array($term->parent), 'product_cat', true);
            $term = get_term($term->parent, 'product_cat');
        }
    }

}
```

Could someone point in the right direction of tweaking the code so that I don't have to save each product individually but rather run it once to update them all?

Again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do the `add_action()` part. Use

```
$products = get_posts(['post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'offset' => 0]);
var_dump(count($products));
foreach ($products as $product) {
    assign_parent_terms($oroduct->ID, $product);
}
```

Refresh page. Increase offset manually with 100 after every refresh until the dump shows 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just tried the code but I am getting the error Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Comment: If it works, can you mark my answer as helpful / correct?

Comment: If the server can't handle 6000 at once do it in steps with the  posts_per_page and limit arguments.

Comment: Sorry we are commenting on top of each other, I will give that a try now

Comment: Try it in steps if say a 100 posts limit. Increase offset with 100 each time you refresh. You will have to refresh 60 times but it is better than saving 6000 posts.

Comment: Again thank you for all your help. I am really not a php user at all, could you break that down for me if you have the time?

Comment: its just the offset part that I am unsure about

Comment: I changed my answer

Comment: Yes like that and then refresh page, make it 200, refresh page, make it 300. Continue until the var dump shows 0